# Custom AppCompatEditText Component not initializing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to implement a custom pin entry text edit field as done in [this](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/building-a-pinentryedittext-in-android-5f2eddcae5d3) tutorial.
I re-wrote the `PinEntryEditText` in Kotlin, and it throws no errors. I also added to my XML layout file, and used it in my MainActivity page. It runs and throws no errors. However, it does not display as it is supposed to. I started trying to debug it and setup 3 breakpoints on each of the class constructors. The debugger does not stop at any of them, which makes me think it never even goes from there.

Now, here is my class :

```
class PinEntryEditText : AppCompatEditText {
    private var mSpace = 24f //24 dp by default, space between the lines
    private var mCharSize: Float = 0.toFloat()
    private var mNumChars = 4f
    private var mLineSpacing = 8f //8dp by default, height of the text from our lines
    private var mMaxLength = 4f
    val XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    var mClickListener: View.OnClickListener? = null

    private var mLineStroke = 1f //1dp by default
    private var mLineStrokeSelected = 2f //2dp by default
    private var mLinesPaint: Paint? = null


    var mStates = arrayOf(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_selected), // selected
            intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_focused), // focused
            intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_focused))// unfocused

    var mColors = intArrayOf(Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, Color.GRAY)

    var mColorStates = ColorStateList(mStates, mColors)


    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        this.setWillNotDraw(false)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        this.setWillNotDraw(false)
        init(context, attrs)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        this.setWillNotDraw(false)
        init(context, attrs)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) {
        val multi = context.resources.displayMetrics.density
        mLineStroke = (multi * mLineStroke)
        mLineStrokeSelected = (multi * mLineStrokeSelected)
        mLinesPaint = Paint(paint)
        mLinesPaint?.strokeWidth = mLineStroke.toFloat()
        if (!isInEditMode) {
            val outValue = TypedValue()
            context.theme.resolveAttribute(colorControlActivated,
                    outValue, true)
            val colorActivated = outValue.data
            mColors[0] = colorActivated

            context.theme.resolveAttribute(colorPrimaryDark,
                    outValue, true)
            val colorDark = outValue.data
            mColors[1] = colorDark

            context.theme.resolveAttribute(colorControlHighlight,
                    outValue, true)
            val colorHighlight = outValue.data
            mColors[2] = colorHighlight
        }
        setBackgroundResource(0)
        mSpace = (multi * mSpace) //convert to pixels for our density
        mLineSpacing = (multi * mLineSpacing) //convert to pixels for our density
        mMaxLength = attrs.getAttributeIntValue(XML_NAMESPACE_ANDROID, "maxLength", 4).toFloat()
        mNumChars = mMaxLength

        //Disable copy paste
        super.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(object : ActionMode.Callback {
            override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode) {}

            override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode, menu: Menu): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode, item: MenuItem): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })
        // When tapped, move cursor to end of text.
        super.setOnClickListener { v ->
            setSelection(text!!.length)
            if (mClickListener != null) {
                mClickListener?.onClick(v)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun setOnClickListener(l: View.OnClickListener?) {
        mClickListener = l
    }

    override fun setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(actionModeCallback: ActionMode.Callback) {
        throw RuntimeException("setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback() not supported.")
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        //super.onDraw(canvas)
        val availableWidth = width - paddingRight - paddingLeft
        if (mSpace < 0) {
            mCharSize = availableWidth / (mNumChars * 2 - 1)
        } else {
            mCharSize = (availableWidth - mSpace * (mNumChars - 1)) / mNumChars
        }

        var startX = paddingLeft.toFloat()
        val bottom = height - paddingBottom

        //Text width
        val text = text
        val textLength = text!!.length
        val textWidths = FloatArray(textLength)
        paint.getTextWidths(getText(), 0, textLength, textWidths)


        for (i in 0..mNumChars.toInt()) {
            updateColorForLines(i == textLength)
            canvas.drawLine(startX.toFloat(), bottom.toFloat(), startX.toFloat() + mCharSize, bottom.toFloat(), paint)
            if (text.length > i) {
                val middle = startX + mCharSize / 2
                canvas.drawText(text, i,i + 1, middle - textWidths[0] / 2, (bottom - mLineSpacing).toFloat(), paint)
            }

            if (mSpace < 0) {
                startX += mCharSize * 2
            } else {
                startX += mCharSize + mSpace
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getColorForState(vararg states: Int): Int {
        return mColorStates.getColorForState(states, Color.GRAY)
    }

    private fun updateColorForLines(next: Boolean) {
        if (isFocused) {
            mLinesPaint?.strokeWidth = mLineStrokeSelected.toFloat()
            mLinesPaint?.color = getColorForState(android.R.attr.state_focused)
            if (next) {
                mLinesPaint?.color = getColorForState(android.R.attr.state_selected)
            }
        } else {
            mLinesPaint?.strokeWidth = mLineStroke.toFloat()
            mLinesPaint?.color = getColorForState(-android.R.attr.state_focused)
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my XML for the component :

```
<com.myapp.app.myapp.PinEntryEditText
    android:id="@+id/pin_entry_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:digits="1234567890"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="4"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Do I have to programmatically assign the class? Unfortunately, I don't really know how to approach this since the debugger won't even step into the class. Any form of input on what could be wrong with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Double check your package name, Your access to the class through package name does not look fine.

Comment: Define "not displaying as it's supposed to" - this can mean quite a lot, and doesn't actually specify an issue

Comment: @HaiderAli That was it, I have no idea how I did not notice that but thank you, if you wanna write a reply I can set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @GiulioColleluori I have answered your question. Please set it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Giulio Colleluori Double check your package name, Your access to the class through package name does not look fine.

Answer (score 1):

According to [View.setWillNotDraw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setWillNotDraw(boolean)), you should remove `setWillNotDraw(true)` from your constructors:

> If this view doesn't do any drawing on its own, set this flag to allow
>   further optimizations. By default, this flag is not set on View, but
>   could be set on some View subclasses such as ViewGroup. Typically, **if
>   you override onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) you should clear this
>   flag**.